# Oracle Database 11g Express Edition - Built-in backup files-to-be-saved

Tags: backup, oracle-11g, xcopy, oraclexe

Considering the built-in 'Backup Database' script (backup.bat) that comes with a new instalation of the Oracle Express 11g Edition, after finishing the script execution, what folders/files should be copied to an external media ('XCOPY' Backup) so the database could be fully restored the database after a new install?

Environment:

- Windows Server 2003
- Database is in ARQCHIVELOG
- Datafiles/Tablespaces are set-up as default (user data is being allocated in USERS Tbs)

**Edit:**

I have a guess that the folder `[InstallDir]\oraclexe\app\oracle\fast_recovery_area` should contain all of what I need, but I'm affraid it isn't enough.